# OfficeDev / office-ui-fabric-react - ChoiceGroup component

Tags: reactjs, redux, office-ui-fabric

I am a newbie with **OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react**, trying to either redefine or modify **ChoiceGroup** component, so instead of having radio buttons as selection options I want to use regular buttons like a **Button Group** from Bootstrap.

If someone has done anything like this and it is able to share any idea I will appreciate any recommendation. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If someone run into the same issue, I found the solution in https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/10727

I hope this will save you a lot of time.
Happy coding